# C++ - What "symbols" should I export to DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, export, symbols

Lets say I have a library project, with defined `XYZ_API` macro as follows:

```
#ifdef XYZ_STATIC
    #define XYZ_API
#else    
    #ifdef XYZ_ACTIVE_PROJECT // macro defined in current project
        #define XYZ_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define XYZ_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#endif
```

What is exactly an exported symbol and which of them should be marked with `XYZ_API` macro? For example:

```
class XYZ_API foo {};

enum class XYZ_API foo {};

template <typename>
class XYZ_API foo {};
```

... or others.

Comment: Do you want other users of your library to be able to access a definition? Export it. Is it only used internally by your library and not part of your library's public API? Don't export it.

Comment: I usually don't put anything that is internal to the `.dll` in a header that I would export so there usually is no time spent deciding what to export.

Comment: Now from the example code you don't export templates.

Comment: But what are the symbols I must export? Static members? functions? methods?

Comment: Export the functions that you want users of your `.dll` to access directly. Don't export functions that you want hidden from the user.